# MVC Kendu UI - Script tag placement

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Can somebody please give me the exact way the scripts should be placed on my layout page.  no matter what way I do it I am getting different error or some controls work and others don't or I am getting javascript errors.

My layout page is like this:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <title>Clients To Profits @ViewBag.Title</title>
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("your logo here", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("User", "Index", "UserView", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("API", "Index", "Help", new { area = "" }, null)</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Pauper To President, Inc.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

      @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@      
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
```

all scripts being registered at the top.  but none of the comboboxes are being rendered correctly, but the date picker is being rendered correctly.  when I register the  jquery bundle at the end right before the closing body tag, none of the controls render correctly, and i get all these js errors:

```
**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined kendo.all.min.js:12
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery' of undefined kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js:11
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined Create:61
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Create:106
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined Create:116**
```

The kendoUI version is at `1.9.1`, but I am actually registering jQuery 2.0.3.  When I try to use 1.9.1 and register it at the bottom I get these errors:

**`GET http://localhost:7731/Scripts/kendo/2013.2.716/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found)`**

**UPDATE - SOLVED**
I ended up creating a new project.  Think the problem was that I had Telerik MVC UI extensions, KenduUI diferent and the diferent versions were conflicting.  Started a new KendoUI Project and everything worked.  Added all my pages from my original project and all the KendoUI stuff still worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should include jQuery before you include the other scripts such as Kendo.  The .map error is something you'll only see in development and as far as I'm aware, you can ignore.

Comment: Thanks you will notice the @scripts.render jQuery is before Kendo and the jquery scrip is commented out at the end of the body tag and i was still getting unexplained results.  my solution was starting a fresh project.  Same setting worked fine